# Error when navigating to a https URL with non standard port on Gingerbread

Tags: android, web-services, ssl

I'm developing an Android App which connects to a webservice located in this URL: "https://awsh.agresso.no:444/"

I can connect from `HoneyComb` to `JellyBean` devices without problems, but I get a SSL error when conneting from a `GingerBread` device.

I first thought it was a problem with KSOAP2-Android, but I tried to navigate from GingerBread standard browser and I got this error: "Data connectivity problem: A secure connection could not be established".

If I navigate from the ICS standard browser, I get the "Access denied" error, which is OK.

Is anyone is experiencing this error?

[image]

Comment: FWIW: can't connect with Opera (stable of opera-next both)... It doesn't recoginize whichever secure protocol you have running. Google-chrome does connect, but you may have to choose another protocol for portability (which that would be I don't know).